# Writing a method to find a number within an Array and returning value

Tags: arrays

I tried search but many of the questions did not involve multiple values. The question I am trying to ask is given an array that represents the number of books own by a library, how can I count the number of books that begin with 'Q' and return that number.

I know that I need to use a charAt() to find the number, i'm just kind of stuck.

```
 class Book {
       String title, author; //title, author
       String callNumber; // call Number, "QA567.23P54"
  }

   Book[] books = new books[27532];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a homework problem. I'll dodge around an exact answer and see if this amount of information helps you make progress.

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    if (books[i].callNumber.charAt(0) == 'Q') {
        System.out.println(books[i].title);
    }
}

for (Book book : books) {
    System.out.println(book.callNumber.charAt(0));
}
```

I've shown you two ways to write a loop through all the books. The first prints the title of the book if it starts with 'Q'. The second prints the first letter of every book title. What I did not do was declare a counter variable to keep track of how many 'Q's are found. See if you can make progress with this -

Comment: Could I essentially take the if statement from the first loop and combine it with the second loop. Then add a variable bookCount or anything incremented after each book with a character at 0?

Comment: @nahoc44 Yes, I believe you are on the right track. Your proposal sounds correct. If you run into any problem implementing it, just ask in another comment and I'll try to help.